# Batch Script, Null value in Reg key returns Error

Tags: batch-file, automation, registry

The below code acquires the IP of IE proxy. Incase there arent any specified, wanted it to return NIL.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%B IN (`REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v  ProxyServer`) DO ( 
    SET ProxyAddress=%%B
    IF "!ProxyAddress!"=="" (
        SET "ProxyAddress=NIL"
    )
Echo %ProxyAddress%
```

But this returns an error, 
`The system was unable to find specified reg key.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should help (set value to `ProxyAddress` variable in advance).

Note `2^>NUL` will redirect error messages to `NUL` (a bottomless pit), cf. [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). Note `>` is escaped with `^` here.

```
SET "ProxyAddress=NIL"
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%B IN (
  `REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v  ProxyServer 2^>NUL`
) DO ( 
    SET "ProxyAddress=%%B"
)
Echo %ProxyAddress%
```